# Openshift - get domain name for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, openshift, openshift-cartridge

In my env variable there is host for MySQL database. But it is ip in local network (starts with 127...). How can I make MySQL available for external world via domain name for db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Openshift is a Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS) that shields the internals of the implementation in a paradigm that allows access through an API connector such as PHP and a database cartidge. Or through SSH tunneling. It does not expose an IP Address of your mysql server sitting there as port 3306 for use in development with such db libraries a c#, java, python, etc. Or with Mysql Workbench or the like.

In fact, it is not your mysql server as much as it is a shared one.

Infrastruture-as-a-Service (IaaS) platforms such as AWS EC2 would allow for those native port 3306 connections and a public IP Address exposed if you opened up the firewall for them.

With Openshift, in order to achieve connections with such things as Mysql Workbench, you need a pki key pair and an SSH tunnel. Same for a native app, say, written in c#, which would need the likes of SSH.NET . these are all configurations that are bearable for a single developer, but don't scale for a rollout to your users, generally speaking. Unless you are up for the task of doing that. That is, key management.

It is one of the drawbacks, but also one of the security guarantees you can bank on. You can also enjoy its simplicity. But it has its shortcomings. I have converted some people away from Openshift once they have realized this. The same limitations exist with major shared hosts where SSH is the only way in.

I hope I have answered your question.